# Is there a way to refresh a page until an element on the screen exists? Only the class is provided

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using C# and Selenium for browser automation, and want to refresh the page until an element exists that matches a given string. How can I do this?

```html
<a class="name-link" href="/shop/sweatshirts/tymdtrivq/wbisud8yv">Breed Crewneck</a>
```

This is how the element looks. I want the page to be refreshed until the text "Breed Crewneck" exists on the page (and then, of course, to click the item). However, I have no access to a name, id, or linktext. Additionally, I cannot use XPath because it has no relationship to the keyword "Breed Crewneck". I believe there is a solution via implementing JavaScript, but I have not gotten far in that prospect.

**EDIT** - prev. edit was removed because of misunderstanding. Apologies.

**EDIT 2**

```cs
bool elementFound = false;

            do
            {
                driver.Navigate().Refresh();
                try
                {
                    driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Breed Crewneck"));
                    elementFound = true;
                }catch(NoSuchElementException error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No such element found!");
                }
            } while (elementFound == false);
```

Above code seems to work. Cheers!

Comment: is the `href` at all related to the `Breed Crewneck`? Oh, and yes, javascript is probably the way forward

Comment: Nope. The "tymdtrivq/wbisud8yv" is unrelated, unfortunately. I suppose I need to find a way to implement a JavaScript function within the C#.

Comment: Oh, in C#, no, then javascript is NOT the way forward

Comment: Ah, ok, so is there a way to solve this via just C#?

Answer (score 0):

Here’s some C# code to refresh the page until the element has the text you are looking for.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 10000);

while (driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class=‘name-link’]")).Text != “Breed Crewneck”)
{

    driver.Navigate().Refresh();
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(“//a[@class=‘name-link’]”)));
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion! The refresh works perfectly, but despite the element existing, the browser constantly reloads. I added a try/catch block around the wait.Until line; it catches NullReferenceExceptions. Any ideas?